# How can I see what the search results in GooglePlay are in different countries for the same search term?

Tags: google-play-store

I have an app and I am wondering where it ranks for a certain GooglePlay search in different countries.

Is there a way to determine that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot see that. There is no such thing, all you can do is just track the activity of your app and see where it is most used. that is all.